# mmap returns ENOMEM with shm_open file object

Tags: linux, shared-memory, mmap, enomem

I'm experimenting with `shm_open` in Linux and I'm running into problems. I'm frequently resizing a shared memory segment with `ftrunc` and using `mmap` to remap the resized segment. However, right around the 20 megabyte mark I get `ENOMEM` from `mmap`.

I have attempted the following to do to resolve the issue:

First, I found out about these `sysctl` parameters. I reconfigured them:

```
kernel.shmmax = 268435456
kernel.shmall = 2097152
```

(`shmall` is specified in pages)

The issue still occurred after this. Investigating the details of the resize that causes the issue revealed that the call made to `ftrunc` to resize the shared memory object succeeded (the corresponding file in `/dev/shm` had the requested new size).

Documentation from [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mmap.html) suggests three possible causes for an `ENOMEM` `errno`:

---

[ENOMEM]
MAP_FIXED was specified, and the range [addr,addr+len) exceeds that allowed for the address space of a process; or, if MAP_FIXED was not specified and there is insufficient room in the address space to effect the mapping.

[ENOMEM]
[ML] The mapping could not be locked in memory, if required by mlockall(), because it would require more space than the system is able to supply.

[ENOMEM]
[TYM] Not enough unallocated memory resources remain in the typed memory object designated by fildes to allocate len bytes.

---

I am not using `MAP_FIXED` or locking, and the size of the image in `/dev/shm` suggests that the third reason is not the problem. My `mmap` call looks like this:

```
mmap(mem, length, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0)
```

where `mem` initially is 0 and thereafter refers to the last address `mmap` successfully mapped.

I found information suggesting that `ulimit` settings could be limiting the memory mappable into a single process, but I don't think the problem was here. Just in case, `ulimit -a` looks like this on my machine:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 20
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 16382
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 65536
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) unlimited
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Comment: The `shmmax` and `shmall` sysctl tunables are for SysV SHM, not POSIX SHM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I misread the documentation for `mmap`, which says that `mmap` returns a mapping based on the first parameter (the previously mapped address in my case), and the result is defined by implementation. I took this as a suggestion that `mmap` might remap my previous mapping for me, but this was certainly not the case. this might only have been the case if I had used the `MAP_FIXED` flag, but I avoided this because the documentation recommended against it.

In any case, it was necessary to use `munmap` to remove the previous mapping before creating a new one.